# How to get a div to stretch right down to a fixed footer

Tags: html, css, height

I wish the two sections of my design (see attached image) to extend the whole height of the page. I have tried to create a Fiddle but it just won't work in there, so [I've put up a link here to demo what I mean](http://savster.byethost4.com).

[image]

I have set the `height` of the `div` that holds the results to `100%`. However, it doesn't stretch right down to the fixed footer.

```
#found-results { 
    height: 100%px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

I also want the green box to stretch down to the footer. The CSS is:

```
.main {
    width: 606px;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 0 0 16px;
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    margin-left: 383px;
}
```

Now, if I add `height: 100%;` to it, it seems to work, but if one of the tabs contains a lot of text, it doesn't stretch far enough.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

### Equal-height columns

In a way, the tricky part isn't the fixed header and footer, or the 100% height; the tricky part is the equal-height columns. Often, it's better to fake equal-height columns (e.g., adding a [grey-green background image](http://www.forestpath.org/test/misc/img/backgrounds/two-column-grey-green-383-624.png) to the parent container). Doing so typically allows the code to be simpler, more flexible, and more stable, compared to true equal-height columns. If the layout for this website proves too unwieldy, try faking the equal-height columns instead (as shown in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/fULCA/4/)), and see if that helps the layout to become more manageable.

With that being said, the basic options for true equal-height columns are as follows:

- HTML tables
- [CSS tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html)
- [CSS3 flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)
- [CSS3 grids](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/)
- JavaScript or jQuery

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/zn3Hd/2/) with true equal-height columns using CSS tables. The left column has very-tall content, and the right column has short content. The demo tested fine in IE10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera; however, this may only work for relatively-simple layouts.

Here's a [similar demo using HTML tables](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/EDAed/3/), in case support for IE8 is needed.

### Faking the equal-height columns

Here's [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/fULCA/4/) that fakes the equal-height columns by adding a [2-color background image](http://www.forestpath.org/test/misc/img/backgrounds/two-column-lt-grey-dk-grey-1000-1000.png). This demo also tested fine in IE10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera; however, unlike the previous ones, it's much more likely to support complex page layouts.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
    <div class="column1">...</div>
    <div class="column2">...</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 120px;
    ...
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    ...
}
#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 120px 0 60px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(some-two-color-background.png) repeat-y 53.6% top;
    ...
}
#content .column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}
#content .column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
}
```

*Note:* The apparent column widths for the background image are controlled by setting the `background-position` property. This allows two columns of any explicit width (px or %) to be faked using the same generic background image. Alternately, a custom background image with the exact column sizes could be used, to simplify the CSS.

Comment: The link to the background image in the fake equal-height example on jsfiddle seems to be broken (edit: it works intermittently, status 403 (forbidden)), ps great in depth answer.

Comment: @TrondHatlen: Thanks for the heads up! I was using imgur.com, but haven't used it enough to know if it's a reliable service. Moved the images to a different server.

Comment: Don't you think that when there is already an answer with a solution provided for a question, which you feel can be improved upon, that your "main example" in your answer then shouldn't be providing the exact same solution which has already been provided earlier?

Comment: @user1846192: With respect, I was an hour into writing my answer when you posted yours. I noticed the similarity, and delayed mine until I could add enough to distinguish it. This was primarily pointing out how equal-height columns are central to the difficulty of the problem, and the suggestion of faking the equal-height columns as a way to simplify things. Your answer addressed neither. Also, when I posted my answer, the version of your answer at the time (prior to Edit2) did not appear to successfully handle very-tall content, and so it seemed incomplete (from what I could tell).

Comment: Hmm, fair enough, it's true that my demo's didn't really 'demonstrate' that they worked fined with tall content at the time you posted your answer, even though the answer contained written down instructions on how to check that they did work fine with tall content (and they did work fine). I just thought that since you mention so many other options, you could have picked another one as your main example, especially since my answer doesn't work in IE8 for example (which using a real table might fix maybe?). **P.S.** You do have a spelling mistake in your CSS and the fiddle: `box-zizing`.

Comment: @user1846192: Good point. I updated the answer with the code for faked equal-height columns, which is the approach I favor anyways. Also added a demo using HTML tables. That should add a little more variety. And thanks for pointing out the typo! I fixed that as well.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are after something like this? <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4ypS/9/)</kbd>

I have made it a bit easier for myself by only copying the markup I needed from your website, the `class`'s, `id`'s and the elements used are exactly the same as on your website, that should make it fairly easy for you to implement this solution on your website.

This layout will always at least fill the whole screen, and both sections will be the same height and touch the fixed footer. When the content is to high for one of the sections, a scroll bar will appear and you can scroll down until you have reached the bottom of both sections. Both sections will always be the same height. I have added some buttons in the header which will add and remove content inside the columns, this makes it easy to see what happens when the content is taller than than the height of the document.

**Edit**

I realised you probably want your header to be fixed as well (as this seems to be the case on your current website), here's a version with a fixed header. <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q4ypS/8/)</kbd>.

**Edit2**

I have added some buttons to the fiddles to make it easier to see what happens when the content inside the columns is forcing the columns to be taller than than the height of the document.

**HTML**

```
<header></header>
<div id="container">
    <section class="results"></section>
    <section class="main"></section>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #333333;
    width: 100%;
}
.main {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #008000;
}
.results {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    width: 383px;
}
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem sits here: `#found-results { height: 100%px; ...`

...and further I think you have to add this too:

```
html, body {height: 100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the height with jquery according to height of sidebar after loading page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main').height($('#sidebar').height());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var footer_h = $("#footer").height();
    var container_height = window_height - footer_h ;
    $("#container").hide();
    $("#container").css('min-height', container_height + "px");
    $("#container").show();
});
```